# can't update input votecount into my database

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Can't update my votecount into my database. I can't figure out why.

Here is the codes. I have dropdown menu, a textfield and submit button. Pick a teacher in dropdown menu, then put scores in textfield then submit button will execute the script

```
<form method='post' action='input_stack.php'>
       <input type='text' name='votecount'>
       <select name='teacher_dropdown'>
       <?php
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value'" . $row['facultyname'] ."'>" . $row['facultyname'] . "</option>";
          }
       ?>
       </select>
       <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit now'>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php mysql_free_result($result);?>
```

and this

```
<?php
$teacherz = isset($_POST['teacher_dropdown']) ? $_POST['teacher_dropdown'] : "";
$votecount = isset($_POST['votecount'])  ? $_POST['teacher_dropdown'] : "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE subj_eva SET facultyname='$teacherz', totalvotes = totalvotes + '$votecount'";
}
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

I'm not sure if it's because of the variable, or option value or maybe the missing WHERE clause.

Comment: You're missing `=` after `value`. Is that the real code or a coying error?

Comment: I asked help for someone, then still not updating, im thinking for about half an hour for where clause which is my prime suspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `WHERE` clause in your query. It should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE subj_eva 
        SET totalvotes = totalvotes + $votecount
        WHERE facultyname = '$teacherz'"
```

You also have a typo in your HTML, you're missing `=` after `value`:

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['facultyname'] ."'>" . $row['facultyname'] . "</option>";
                   ^
```

You're setting the `$votecount` variable from the wrong `$_POST` variable, it should be:

```
$votecount = isset($_POST['votecount'])  ? $_POST['votecount'] : 0;
```

You should also upgrade to either PDO or mysqli, so you can use a prepared statement. Otherwise, you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to sanitize the input.

Comment: still not working :( I uploaded the pic of my database, and im pretty sure im not wrong in naming of column in php

Comment: thanks again, but still not working, I already put = in option value

Comment: See my latest update. Maybe you should do some real debugging, like printing your variable values.

Comment: still not working.. ok thanks mate for your effort, I really need to debug this now my life is at stake :D

Comment: Do you get an error message if you `echo mysql_error()` after the query?

Comment: What if you `echo $sql` and then run that query by hand?